# Why mine type change in getID3

Tags: php, getid3

I'm calling this bellow method as GetID3MIMEtype('test.docx')
That method change file type to "application/zip" but i'm not upload any zip file this not correct file type.

```
 function GetID3MIMEtype($filename) {
      $filename = realpath($filename);
      $getID3 = new getID3;
      $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($filename);
      getid3_lib::CopyTagsToComments($ThisFileInfo);      
      log_error(print_r($ThisFileInfo['mime_type'], true));
      if (empty($ThisFileInfo['error'])) {
         if ($ThisFileInfo['fileformat']) {
            $temp = explode("/", $ThisFileInfo['mime_type']);
            $mime = $temp[0]."/".$ThisFileInfo['fileformat'];
         }
         else
            $mime = $ThisFileInfo['mime_type'];
         return $mime;
      }
      else {
         log_error("ID 3 Error - ".$filename." - ".print_r($ThisFileInfo['error'], true));
         return false;
      }
   }
```

Question

1. What is [getID3](http://www.getid3.org/) class
2. Why this class change file Mine Type

Comment: [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.docx` file *is* a zip file - try renaming it to `.zip` and opening it. You'll see it's a collection of XML and other embedded documents.

That said, `getId3` is designed to be used on Multimedia file types - video and audio files - as it says on the [project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/)

It's a Mime Type not a Mine Type. It's similar to a file extension but more powerful. It lets different applications (possibly on different platforms) know how a specific file should be handled. Try reading [this page](http://www.hunnysoft.com/mime/mime-guide.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in this getID3 libary; at least in the current version `getid3-1.9.5-20130220`.

If you open the file `module.archive.zip.php` and change the block

```
if (!empty($ThisFileInfo['zip']['files']['ppt'])) {
  $info['mime_type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
} elseif (!empty($ThisFileInfo['zip']['files']['xl'])) {
  $info['mime_type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
} elseif (!empty($ThisFileInfo['zip']['files']['word'])) {
  $info['mime_type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
}
```

to

```
if (!empty($info['zip']['files']['ppt'])) {
  $info['mime_type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
} elseif (!empty($info['zip']['files']['xl'])) {
  $info['mime_type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
} elseif (!empty($info['zip']['files']['word'])) {
  $info['mime_type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
}
```

(i.e. change `$ThisFileInfo` to `$info`)

the mime type changes from `application/zip` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` for a word .docx